# Freshly installed Ubuntu12.04 with no sound at laptop speakers but working on headsets!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am really new to Ubuntu and i just got installed it.

The problem is that i can not turn on my Laptop sounds. My laptop is Sony Vaio SVF1521B1E.
When i connect my headset to the laptop they are working and they have sound.

But there is no sound from my laptop speakers. How i can fix that?

I have tried many things.

```
sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for venelin: 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have added this `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and rebooted my laptop but still no sounds from my laptop speakers.

So please tell me how i can fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad driver. Go to terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install jockey
```

Comment: When i scan for drivers it's not giving me any sound drivers. Only Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`sudo aptitude install linux-backports-modules-alsa-precise-generic`

use apt-get update and upgrade commands if packages won't start installing.

Don't forget to reboot the OS after all of this so it take effect. And after restart check in the panel if the sound is not muted.